# Как вычленить из текста ФИО на python, при том что конкретных шаблонов нет?

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Как можно достать ФИО из текста(текста могут быть абсолютно разными и не иметь ничего общего), учитывая что ФИО всегда в формате 'Фамилия Имя Отчество', но в нем могут быть ошибки либо неправильный регистр, например: 'Кравец арртем вячеславович', 'морозова ЕЛЕНа викторовна' и тп, а также встречаются ФИО с двойными фамилиями('Багашвили-Багаев Артем Викторович'), и есть редкие фамилии ('Ырлгай', 'Аксаков' и тп.)?

Пытался использовать библиотеки natasha и yangy, но наташа не находит все варианты, а yangy либо не находит, любо я не смог нормально настроить.

Comment: Посмотрите https://github.com/natasha/natasha

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать через регулярные выражения, опираясь на окончания [отчеств](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE).

```
import re

txt = """dfdlfdkf Багашвили-Багаев Артем Викторович dlkfm.qfefw
Багашвили-Багаев Артем Викторович dlkfm.qfefw
1512в5 Кравец арртем вячеславович ужолт 
hjdfdjsh  dh bdh морозова ЕЛЕНа викторовна lj qldkjf qjkhfd qlkjfdh lq
d;kljnf;d раз-два-три Иван Никитич"""

for s in txt.split('\n'):
    result = re.search(r'(?:^|\s)([а-яА-ЯёЁ]+(?:-[а-яА-ЯёЁ]+)?\s[а-яА-ЯёЁ]+\s[а-яА-ЯёЁ]+(?:ович|евич|ич|овна|евна|ична|иничнa))', s)
    if result:
        print(result.group(1).title())
```

```
Багашвили-Багаев Артем Викторович
Багашвили-Багаев Артем Викторович
Кравец Арртем Вячеславович
Морозова Елена Викторовна
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать библиотеку [PyMystem3](https://pypi.org/project/pymystem3/). Полный обзор я вам не сделаю, но минимальный пример для решения Вашей проблемы предоставляю:

```
from pymystem3 import Mystem

text = 'один два три четыре пять петРов ИвАн АндрееВИЧ шесть семь восемь 9.'

m = Mystem()

analyze = m.analyze(text)

first_name = None
second_name = None
middle_name = None

for word in analyze:
    try:
        analysis = word['analysis'][0]
    except KeyError:
        continue

    if 'имя' in analysis['gr']:
        first_name = word['text'].capitalize()
    elif 'фам' in analysis['gr']:
        second_name = word['text'].capitalize()
    elif 'отч' in analysis['gr']:
        middle_name = word['text'].capitalize()

print(f'{second_name} {first_name} {middle_name}')
```

Результат:
`Петров Иван Андреевич`